# Can I post just JSON as data in Angular?

Tags: angular, post, content-type, angular-http

In angular 4, How can I post just JSON as data?

Currently, my post code is:

```
let options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
};

let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

urlSearchParams.append('key', 'value');

let bodyString = urlSearchParams.toString();

return this.http.post(api, bodyString, options);
```

As you can see I am using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `URLSearchParams` before `post`. (which is working)

I think there will be a way to use just `JSON`. (e.g. `this.http.post(api, MY_JSON)`)

I have tried `new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')` but no luck.

The below is what I want :

```
let options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json)
};

return this.http.post(api, MY_JSON, options);
```

If I post like the above, everything is correctly posted but no reaction from the server.

Should I check back-end?

Comment: URL search parameters are for query strings, e.g. `?key=value`, *in the URL*. What exactly should the *payload*, the body of the request, be? You *can* pass arrays and objects to post and have them serialised.

Comment: If you are using the json content-type header, you can pass in the json object as the 2nd parameter of .post()

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added more explain. I know that URLSearchParams is for query string. However, seems it's only way to post in angular so far for me. If there is no problem in the 'The below is what I want' code, should I check back-end?

Comment: Well if you look at the request in tests or the browser, does it have the structure you expect? Yes, I think you need to check the server.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes I see the structure what I expect when i post in the network tab in Chrome. Just I wasn't sure if I'm doing anything wrong in front-end. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was back-end configuration.

In symfony3(PHP), simply run json_decode() to get json from front-end.